# Syntax for a single function module targeting the browser and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, module

If I'm writing a JavaScript module for the browser, I'd assign it to `window`:

```
window.myModule = function(){ };
```

For node, I'd assign it to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = function(){ };
```

What's the cleanest syntax for handling all scenarios?  My current code is pretty gross:

```
(function(container, containerKey){
    container[containerKey] = function(){ };
})(module ? module : window, module ? 'exports' : 'myModule');
```

[I've seen examples like this](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser), but the export is an object.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073100/193896) is close, but I want to export directly to module (I don't want the extra qualifier).

Comment: Had a look at [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)? The drawback is that it requires you to run a build script and use different files for browser and node. And some hacks to make it available on window instead of through "require()" in the browser.

Comment: Otherwise i think one of the solutions offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673346/supporting-both-commonjs-and-amd) should work for functions as well as objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Files communication with coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287510/multiple-files-communication-with-coffeescript)

Comment: @AaronDufour Your link is a question about coffeescript, plus the accepted answer assigns a module with an extra qualifier.

Comment: @bendytree The translation to javascript requires just a few extra parens, and I thought it was pretty close, but I'd be happy to make the small changes and repost it here.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [Multiple Files communication with coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287510/multiple-files-communication-with-coffeescript)

Basically, we choose whether to run server-side or client-side code based on which environment we're in.  This is the most common way to do it:

```
if(typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
  //On a server
  module.exports = ChatService;
} else {
  //On a client
  window.ChatService = ChatService;
}
```

To get it:

```
if(typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
  //On a server
  ChatService = require("ChatService.coffee");
} else {
  //On a client
  ChatService = window.ChatService;
}
```

The else clause of the second block can be skipped, since `ChatService` already refers to the reference attached to `window`.

Note that your current code will crash with a ReferenceError on the client, unless `module` happens to be declared somewhere.